# I want to make EditText hint to get in centre. Android studio 2.3.1

Tags: android-layout

I have given android:layout_gravity="center", still unable to get it in center. 
Please give me solution in XML itself. I am a beginner, so please give simple solution so that I can understand, please bear with me even if you found this so silly.Thank you. [image: Screenshot of my problem]

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:gravity="center"`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score -1):

See my updated answer:

```
    <EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
/>
```